# DockerFile: Is it use to create an image or To the docker host how to create the container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am confused with some terms.

Is `Dockerile` designed to create an image or a set of instruction of how to create a container from an image?

Because there are command e.g. `FROM` (to get the base image), `RUN` (To run executable in the container) etc. These command looks like an instruction to how to create the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker images are static, and are built from the instructions specified in the `Dockerfile`. They use Union File-System (UnionFS), so that the changes made when building an image are stacked on top of each other, generating a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) of build history. The `FROM` directive at the top of the `Dockerfile` simply points to an existing image, and starts building on top of that.

A container is simply an instantiated version of an image, basically just this UnionFS with a read/write layer dropped on top of it.

Interestingly, if you watch the output when you run `docker build` (in a directory with a `Dockerfile`) you'll see that what is happening is each instruction starts up a container based on the current state of the image, runs the command (`apt-get install ...` or whatever) and then `commit`s that change to the image. That's why it's good to batch up commands in a `Dockerfile` - because each one will start a new container.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual Studio to do the create a project. The project has the docker support which will create a docker file automatically. Will I ever need to touch or modify the docker file?

Answer (score 0):

[Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) is used to create an image which you can later use to create a container using `docker build`.

From the docs

> Docker can build images automatically by reading the instructions from a Dockerfile. A Dockerfile is a text document that contains all the commands a user could call on the command line to assemble an image. Using docker build users can create an automated build that executes several command-line instructions in succession.

Also `RUN` will instruction will execute any commands in a **new layer** on top of the current image and **commit the results**. The resulting committed image will be used for the next step in the `Dockerfile` and not "Run (To run executable in the container)". For details see [this](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/builder/#run).

Answer (score 0):

**Image:**
`Docker engine` use `Dockerfile` reference to build up `Image` from `Dockerfile` instruction like (FROM, RUN etc.)

**Container:** 
`Docker engine` start container from `Image` and we can say `Container` is RUN time instance of `Image`